# Position option in jQuery UI menu: y axis can only be centered (top/bottom come out as center). (Bug?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've set up a menu to run horizontally across the top of the screen (by floating top-level `li`'s to the left).  The submenu default position is `my left top left at right top`.  I want it to be `my right top at right bottom`, so it won't interfere with movement in the top-level menu.  When I specify this (or any other value), the y-axis is always positioned at center.  I've tried using various pixel adjustments as well, with no change.

Sounds suspiciously like a value is being set to zero when it shouldn't be, so I smell a bug.  Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rua3v2sb/26/) and here's my code:

```
$('#topMenu').menu({
    select: function( event, ui ) { alert('selected ' + ui.item.text());
    },        
    position: {
        my: 'right-top',
        at: 'right-bottom'
    },
    icons: {
        submenu: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'
    }
});
```

I'm using jQuery-ui 1.11.4.  I've also tried using previous versions with the same result, as far back as 1.8.0 (although that one had other problems as well).  Can anyone show me why this isn't a bug?

EDIT: I was able to go into jquery-ui.js and make a change that fixed this, so now I'm pretty darn sure it's a bug.  Here's the relevant code, starting at line 6363:

```
var menu = $.widget( "ui.menu", {
    version: "1.11.4",
    defaultElement: "<ul>",
    delay: 300,
    options: {
        icons: {
            submenu: "ui-icon-carat-1-e"
        },
        items: "> *",
        menus: "ul",
        position: {
            my: "left-1 top",
            at: "right top"
        },
        role: "menu",

        // callbacks
        blur: null,
        focus: null,
        select: null
    },
```

I changed the position option so:

```
position: {
    my: "right top",
    at: "right bottom"
},
```

and got the positioning I was looking for.  Obviously this isn't a fix (although it works--for now--as a hack for what I need to do, since I only have one type of menu in my application), but it does seem to demonstrate that there's a problem in the jquery-ui code with picking up the user settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to delete this, even though the solution leaves me wiping egg off my face.  I'm leaving it up because it's pretty funny, and it's a particularly good example of what happens when you need to quit and you're too busy obsessing over a minor problem.

As jakecigar in the jQuery forum pointed out, in my code up top there are hyphens in the values for `my` and `at`. In the jQuery code there aren't.  Removing the hyphens solved the problem!